# Entity class and encapsulation confusion - how do you call a non-static method from main()?

Tags: java, encapsulation

I am creating a class called "Crate" that will read an input file of integers representing objects dimensions in inches and output a report containing the crate sizes required for each respective item.  Everything seemed fine until I tried to test my methods, as I am unable to call them from main().  When trying, I get an error message saying, "non-static method createReport() cannot be referenced from a static context."

I am a beginner, so if anything is fundamentally wrong I will happily accept criticism.  I am just curious if there is a simple fix to this and what my gap in knowledge is regarding static/non-static methods.

```
package crate;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Crate {
    private Crate[] crateList;
    private int crateAmount;
    private int height, width, depth, panels;
    private int smallestCratePosition, smallestCrateSize;
    private int largestCratePosition, largestCrateSize;
    private double averageCrateSize;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        createReport();
    }
    
    public Crate() {
        height = 1;
        width = 1;
        depth = 1;
        panels = 6;
    }
    
    public void createReport() throws IOException {
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File("ShippingSizes.txt"));
        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new File("CrateReport.txt"));
        
        createCrateList(infile);
        
        outfile.println("There are " + crateAmount + " crates.");
        for (int i = 0; i < crateList.length; i++) {
            outfile.println(i + ": height=" + crateList[i].getHeight() + ", width=" + 
                    crateList[i].getWidth() + ", depth=" + crateList[i].getDepth() + 
                    ", panels=" + crateList[i].getPanels());
        }
        outfile.println("\n" + "Smallest crate is at " + smallestCratePosition + 
                ": height=" + crateList[smallestCratePosition].getHeight() + ", width=" + 
                crateList[smallestCratePosition].getWidth() + ", depth=" + 
                crateList[smallestCratePosition].getDepth() + ", panels=" + 
                crateList[smallestCratePosition].getPanels());
        outfile.println("Largest crate is at " + largestCratePosition + ": height," + 
                crateList[largestCratePosition].getHeight() + ", width=" + 
                crateList[largestCratePosition].getWidth() + ", depth=" + 
                crateList[largestCratePosition].getDepth() + ", panels=" + 
                crateList[largestCratePosition].getPanels());
        outfile.println("Average crate size is: " + averageCrateSize);
        
        outfile.close();
        infile.close();
    }
    
    public void setCrateDimensions(Scanner scnr) {
        int tempValue = scnr.nextInt();
        height = tempValue/12;
        if (tempValue%12 != 0)
            height++;
        
        tempValue = scnr.nextInt();
        width = tempValue/12;
        if (tempValue%12 != 0)
            width++;
        
        tempValue = scnr.nextInt();
        depth = tempValue/12;
        if (tempValue%12 != 0)
            depth++;
        
        panels = 2*((height*width)+(height*depth)+(width*depth));
    }
    
    public void createCrateList(Scanner scnr) {
        crateAmount = scnr.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < crateAmount; i++) {
            crateList[i].setCrateDimensions(scnr);
        }
    }
    
    public void getSmallestCrate() {
        smallestCrateSize = crateList[0].getPanels();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < crateList.length; i++) {
            if (crateList[i].getPanels() < smallestCrateSize) {
                smallestCratePosition = i;
                smallestCrateSize = crateList[i].getPanels();
            }          
        }
    }
    
    public void getLargestCrate() {
        largestCrateSize = crateList[0].getPanels();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < crateList.length; i++) {
            if (crateList[i].getPanels() > largestCrateSize) {
                largestCratePosition = i;
                largestCrateSize = crateList[i].getPanels();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void getAverageCrateSize() {
        double totalPanels = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < crateList.length; i++)
            totalPanels += crateList[i].getPanels();
        averageCrateSize = totalPanels / (double)(crateList.length);
    }
    
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    
    public int getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }
    
    public int getPanels() {
        return panels;
    }
}
```

I tried declaring the Scanner, PrintWriter, Crate[] object, and crateAmount integer inside of main(), however this only led to the same issue later on as I was unable to use those variables in my methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can read about this phenomenon here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-static methods belong to an instance of a class, not the class itself. This is why you can't access the `createReport()` method from `main()`, because main is in the static scope, while createReport is not. Try instantiating an instance of the class and calling `createReport()` on the object.

For example:

```
Crate crate = new Crate();
crate.createReport();
```

Answer (score 1):

because the `createReport` method is related to it's instance of Class Crate.
you must create an instance by `new` keywords, then you can call it's method `createReport`.

another way, if you don't want create an instance of class, you can declared method to static method by keyword `static`. then the method will be load when starting the jvm.

suggestion: you should deeply understand the OOP programming by reading an book or another article